# I think my Android app is crashing due to Firebase configuration issues

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, firebase-authentication, runtimeexception

I made a login and a registration acitivty with Firebase. When I start the app I get lot of exceptions. I think it is not due to the syntax but due to the configuration.

**Registration**

```
class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private  lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    //Email und Passwort Eingabefelder
    val regEmail: EditText = findViewById(R.id.registration_email)
    val regPassword: EditText = findViewById(R.id.registration_password)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        //Button der gedrückt wird zum Registrieren nach dem man seine Daten eingegeben hat
        val registration_button: Button = findViewById(R.id.registration_button)
        registration_button.setOnClickListener {
            //WENN Button gedrückt DANN rufe FUNKTION auf
            createUser()
        }


        //Zurück zum login
        val login_texView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.loginLink_textView)
        login_texView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent_registration_activiy = Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent_registration_activiy)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function: createUser
     * Eingegebene Email und Passwort werden in Strings umgewandelt
     * Danach wird überprüft ob die Email und Passwort Felder leer sind
     * IF Leer DANN Error und Focus
     * SONST:
     * User wird erstellt mit eingegebener email und passwort
     * Es wird danach überprüft ob die Registrierung erfolgreich war oder nicht
     * WENN erfolgreich: Toast, Weiterleitung zum Login
     * SONST: Toast
     *
     */
    private fun createUser(){
        val email: String = regEmail.text.toString()
        val password: String = regPassword.text.toString()

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            regEmail.setError("E-mail kann nicht leer sein")
            regEmail.requestFocus()
        } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            regPassword.setError("Passwort kann nicht leer sein")
            regPassword.requestFocus()
        } else{
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    val successfull_toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Registrierung erfolgreich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    successfull_toast.show()
                    val intent_logIn_activity = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent_logIn_activity)
                } else {
                    val unsuccsessfull_toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten " + task.exception?.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    val logEmail: EditText = findViewById(R.id.userLogInEmail)                  //email zum einloggen
    val logPassword: EditText = findViewById(R.id.userLogInPassword)            //passwort zum einloggen
    val logButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.logIn_button)                     //Button zum einloggen
    val regLink: TextView = findViewById(R.id.registration_textView)            //Zur Registration Activity

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        //Login Button OnClick
        logButton.setOnClickListener {
            loginUser()
        }
        //Klicke und komme zur Registrations Activity
        regLink.setOnClickListener {
            val intent_regActivity = Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent_regActivity)
        }
    }

    private fun loginUser(){
        val email: String = logEmail.text.toString()
        val password: String = logPassword.text.toString()

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            logEmail.setError("Email kann nicht leer sein")
            logEmail.requestFocus()
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            logPassword.setError("Passwort kann nicht leer sein")
            logPassword.requestFocus()
        } else {
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    val successfull_toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Login erfolgreich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    successfull_toast.show()
                    val intent_mainActivity = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent_mainActivity)
                } else {
                    val unsuccessfull_toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Login nicht möglich " + task.exception?.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    unsuccessfull_toast.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    /**
     * Wenn die App startet wird überprüft ob der User angemeldet ist oder nicht bzw. einen Account hat
     * IF NOT gehe zur Login-Acitiviy
     */
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val user = auth.currentUser
        if(user == null){
            val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the app I get these exceptions:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Configuration `:app:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies, but the `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which may cause runtime issues.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0) and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
Configuration `:app:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies, but the `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which may cause runtime issues.
Set `android.useAndroidX=true` in the `gradle.properties` file and retry.
The following AndroidX dependencies are detected:
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.core:core:1.2.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.core:core:1.2.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.core:core:1.2.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.core:core:1.2.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0 -> androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0 -> androidx.core:core:1.2.0 -> androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 -> androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0 -> androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 -> androidx.print:print:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
:app:debugRuntimeClasspath -> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.6 -> androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 -> androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try what it's suggesting in the error message? It's pretty helpful!

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException:
 Configuration `:app:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies,
 but the `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which may cause runtime issues.
```

Your app is using [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) dependencies (i.e. the modern version of the Support Library and the Jetpack components) but you've not actually enabled the `useAndroidX` property

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class
 android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules
 core-1.2.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.2.0)
 and support-compat-28.0.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
```

You're using AndroidX libraries **and** the old Support library, and those conflict with each other - here the same class exists in both and that's causing a `RuntimeException` during your build, i.e. a crash.

There's no need for a modern app to use the Support Library anymore, and it's [recommended you move to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/) since that's what's being developed and what your other dependencies use.

```
Configuration `:app:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies,
 but the `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which may cause runtime issues.
 Set `android.useAndroidX=true` in the `gradle.properties` file and retry.
```

And here it's telling you how to fix it - add that property in your `gradle.properties` file. You might also want to add `android.enableJetifier=true` to that file [as the docs explain](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx#using_androidx_libraries_in_your_project).

If you're using AndroidX, make sure you change all your `support` dependencies to the `androidx` equivalents in your module-level `build.gradle` file. [You can migrate to AndroidX automatically](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio) using a command in Android Studio - I've never used it, but it's there. That link tells you more about the migration process and stuff you need to look out for